# Display html in unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, awesomium

I'm working on a Unity App where I need to load some html pages(with touch support).
I've found 3 plugins for that and each have some limitations. Are there any other good plugins so I can test and see.
These are the ones I'm currently testing
uWebKit - having a issue with higher resolutions(when swiping the carousal it gets slow with higher resolutions)
Coherent UI - Doesn't support touch events. Have to write code to make touch works properly.
Awesomium - Didn't test this, because it seems bit too expensive.

If any of you know of any other plugins for that please list them.

Thanks

Comment: For anyone looking for an answer, I ended up using Coherent UI plugin and that seem to do the work I needed. Their new version supported touch events also, didn't have to write code for that.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried PowerUI (http://powerui.kulestar.com/) it is a plugin which renders HTML within Unity directly. (Rather than using an external web renderer, and then copying the texture into Unity).

It only renders a subset of HTML/JS, so it is primarily suited to building up interfaces from scratch, but it is quite useful, fast, and I believe it supports touch events.